# Does the definition of continuity of $f(x,y)$ defined on a region $R \subseteq\mathbb R^2$ with boundary points allow $f$ to be continuous on $R$?

Tags: calculus

> Does the definition of continuity of a function of several variables $f(x,y)$ defined on a region $R \subseteq\mathbb R^2$ with boundary points allow $f$ to be continuous on $R$ ?

I've been reading carefully in Calculus books, and as I see it, continuity of $f$ is defined only at a point $(a,b) \in R$ such that the open circle $B_r(a,b) \subseteq R$ centered at $(a,b)$ lies entirely wihtin $R$. I cannot create an open circle at a boundary point.

However in order to use a theorem in Probability I assume that $f$ has continuous partial derivatives on $R$. But in my case $R$ has boundary points, so I cannot conclude continuity of the partial derivatives even thus they exists for all interior points ? Also I cannot conclude continuity of $f$ on $R$ ?

Comment: Related: a continuously differentiable function $f$ on a closed set $D$ is usually defined to be so that there exists an open set $D\subset U$ for which $f$ can be extended to a continuously differentiable on the open set.

Comment: So we can extend $f$ to the open set $U$ ? Can you provide me with a link to the definition ?

Comment: Definition 22 - http://math.arizona.edu/~glickenstein/math534_1011/Chap2.pdf